# how to make malware file readable with “No read permission on file” on linux ext-4?

Tags: permissions, ext4, malware

There is an ongoing campaign of sending virus/trojans in e-mail messages faked as being from HSBC Bank, Lloyds TSB, Amazon etc.

The trojan/virus is sent in a application/zip attachment.

I've saved one such zip file and unpacked it in a directory owned by me with permission 700 on an ext4 file system

In order to scan it with `clamscan`, `avgscan`, and `avast`, I've saved the zip file and unpacked its contents into a directory "virus":

```
File: /home/users/miller/virus
Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 809h/2057d      Inode: 14155801    Links: 2
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1001/  miller)   Gid: ( 1000/   users)
Access: 2013-10-03 12:57:47.484923866 +0200
Modify: 2013-10-03 12:57:46.684879168 +0200
Change: 2013-10-03 12:57:46.684879168 +0200
Birth: -
```

As to be expected I can rename the file or delete it. The file has permissions 600 and is owned by me:

```
$ stat virus.exe
File: virus.exe
Size: 61440           Blocks: 120        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 809h/2057d      Inode: 14155809    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1001/  miller)   Gid: ( 1000/   users)
Access: 2013-10-03 12:46:37.194541504 +0200
Modify: 2013-10-01 22:01:44.000000000 +0200
Change: 2013-10-03 13:19:09.263393591 +0200
Birth: -`
```

But any attempt to read the file or copy it fails.

```
$ file virus.exe
virus.exe: writable, regular file, no read permission`

cp virus.exe copy.exe
cp: cannot open virus.exe for reading: Operation not permitted`

lsattr virus.exe 
lsattr: Operation not permitted While reading flags on virus.exe`
```

Even trying this as root fails.

So how is it possible to make a file unreadable even though it has "rw permission" and how can it be made readable in order to scan it with `avgscan`, `clamscan`, `avast` etc?

---

* CORRECTION ****   (previous comment was for wrong zip file)

Addendum:  Running `clamscan` on the saved attachment zip file its-self results in no virus/trojan/malware being detected, probably because the internal executable file is in an "unreadable" state.

clamscan virus.zip
virus.zip: OK

Similarly `avgscan` and `avast` fail to detect any malware.

This highlights the importance of being able to read the extracted exe file and shows that `clamscan` is failing to detect malware.

The original name of the zip file is `ORDER-N:N-1414559-3015133.zip` and the original name of the executable file is `Order details.exe`.

---

*** IMPORTANT ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ***

To recap, if the zip file is unpacked by user miller, an exe file is created:

```
60 -rw-------   1 miller users 61440 2013-10-01 22:01 Order details.exe
```

but this is unreadable either by user miller or root.

HOWEVER, if the zip file is unpacked by root, the exe file is readable by root:

```
0 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 61440 2013-10-01 22:01 Order details.exe
```

The file command shows the following:

```
[15:57] koala:{virus/}# file Order\ details.exe 
Order details.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

So what is set that is preventing the ordinary user and root from reading the file unpacked by the user?

The file unpacked by root:

```
$ lsattr Order\ details.exe 
-------------e-- Order details.exe
```

The manual page for `chattr` explains:

```
The 'e' attribute indicates that the file is using extents for  mapping
the blocks on disk.  It may not be removed using chattr(1).
```

Thus on the ext2/3/4 file systems there is a catch22 situation -- the lack of readability of the file **CANNOT** be changed, and the solution is to unpack the zip archive as root to avoid creating the unpacked file with the "e" attribute since Linux unzip version does not have an ignore attributes switch.

If the zip file is unpacked on an XFS file system by the user, then it is readable, because XFS does not support the attribute setting mechanism.

And when `avgscan` is run on the exe file:

```
$ avgscan Order\ details.exe 
AVG command line Anti-Virus scanner
Copyright (c) 2013 AVG Technologies CZ

Virus database version: 3222/6719
Virus database release date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 06:11:00 +0200

Order details.exe  Found Luhe.Fiha.A

Files scanned     :  1(1)
Infections found  :  1(1)
```

So the moral of this story is ***do not trust*** `avgscan`, `avast`, or `clamscan` on always finding malware in zip files -- always do the scan on the unpacked executable!

Comment: clamscan virus.exe 
WARNING: Can't open file virus.exe: Operation not permitted

Comment: Run `df /home/users/miller/virus`. As user miller, run `file viruses.exe`.

Comment: df /home/users/miller/virus
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9      450872512 193986816 233982680  46% /home

Comment: I included the output of file virus.exe in the ORIGINAL message -- file virus.exe
virus.exe: writable, regular file, no read permission`

Comment: The distribution is Linux Mint 14 Nadia (based on Ubuntu Quantal 12.10) The kernel is 3.5.0-41-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP file is version 5.11-2  coreutils is version 8.13-3.2ubuntu

Comment: Please run this: `blkid | grep sda9`.

Comment: Wasn't sure if the output was from you running it or root that's why I asked again for it!

Comment: No ecryptfs involved (I believe Ubuntu has defaulted to using ecryptfs for some time now)? No online virus scanner which might intercept the read syscalls and block them based on a virus being detected? Try booting in single user mode and doing the same things; does it work any better?

Comment: Clamscan should be able to scan the zip file directly too. Doesn't solve you Q but just an FYI.

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158139/hown-to-make-virus-file-readable-with-no-read-permission-on-file-on-linux-ext. The question really belongs here.

Comment: @JGMiller - very nice detective work!

Comment: Please consider summarizing your findings (the "Important Additional Information" section) in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the smoking gun is this command:

```
lsattr virus.exe 
lsattr: Operation not permitted While reading flags on virus.exe
```

This is basically saying that the underlying file system is not EXT2/3/4. Given that the normal permissions can sometimes not be a factor and file attributes may well not be supported either.

#### Example

I have an NFS mounted share as follows.

```
$ pwd
/home/sam
```

If I run `lsattr` against it:

```
$ lsattr /home/sam/ 2>&1 | head -3
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/sam/dead.letter
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/sam/bashrc
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/sam/phillip_phillips_home.mp3
```

My guess is that the filesystem is what's denying you access to it.

Comment: This is a good point to make.  However the file virus.exe is in /home/users/miller/virus which is definitely on an ext4 file system

Comment: df -h /home/users/miller/virus
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9       430G  186G  224G  46% /home
[15:30] koala:{~/virus/}> mount | grep sda9
/dev/sda9 on /home type ext4 (rw)

Comment: @JGMiller Do you have an antivirus running that could possibly block access to the file?